# ffmpeg commands for merge the image with video file in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am working on add watermark on video file in android with the use of ffmpeg jni what i have not found any solution for the same . i am using this command  "ffmpeg -i alldone.mp4 -i cancel_bttn.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2" record.mp4 " but this was not worked.